# OpenLayers v6.5.0: How to create a non-intersecting polygon passing through all given points

Tags: polygon, openlayers

Is there any function/library that I can use to create a non-intersecting polygon?
Below is the code that I used to draw Polygon from the specified points but it is not working for the non-intersecting part.

```
  public drawPolygon(points: LonLat[]): Feature {
   let coordinates =  [];
   points.forEach(function (point) {
    coordinates.push(fromLonLat([point.lon, point.lat]))
   });
   let feature = new Feature(new Polygon([coordinates]));
   return feature;
  }
```

Comment: One possibility would be to use `turf.concave` method from turf.js library: https://turfjs.org/docs/#concave

Comment: Thanks for your help. At the end I solved it by using convex hull.

Comment: You can publish your solution as an answer to your own question, to help others with similar questions/problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a solution for my problem:

```
public drawPolygon(points: LonLat[]): Feature {
 let coordinates : Coordinate[] =  [];

 points.forEach(function (point) {
  coordinates.push(fromLonLat([point.lon, point.lat]))
 });

 let convexHullCoordinates = this.convexHull(coordinates);
 let feature = new Feature(new Polygon([convexHullCoordinates]));
 return feature;
}
```